# Could verbぞ be an order or request?

Tags: imperatives, clusivity

For example:

> 負けないぞ

> 頑張るぞ

Could these sentences be used to ask other people to perform things above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is, no.

Following are not orders, not requests:

- あなたは頑張るぞ (you)
- あなたたちは頑張るぞ (you guys)
- 彼は頑張るぞ (he)
- 彼らは頑張るぞ (those guys)
- みんなは頑張るぞ (everyone)
- 私は寝るけどみんなは頑張るぞ (everyone except for me)

---

Following may be subjective:

- 私たちは頑張るぞ (we)
- みんなで頑張るぞ (us)

These are not orders, not requests, but has the nuance " let's 頑張る ". If your boss says 「みんなで頑張るぞ」 (let's do this together) you can consider that's an order or being voluntold.